# Why is my postgreSQL query saying it is undefined when it's not on my terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to make a node.js app that keeps track of the amount of messages sent using postgreSQL as backend.  postgreSQL query returns undefined when I do it in javascript but when I do it on terminal, it returns the row (that I manually inserted before to make sure it actually gets found) perfectly fine.

Whenever I do it on terminal, it shows this:

```
database => SELECT * FROM xp WHERE id = '210871461580242946';
     id         | xp
--------------------+----
 210871461580242946 |  1
```

However, when I'm trying to run my javascript code that runs this:

```
pool.query(`SELECT * FROM xp WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`, (err, results) => {
    if (err) console.log("err = " + err);

    console.log("results = " + results);
    console.log("results[0] = " + results[0]);
```

This is what is printed to the console:

```
results = [object Object]
results[0] = undefined
```

why is results[0] undefined?

Comment: Maybe the query returned zero rows?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that I made sure it returns a row because I added an id of myself manually and tested it on the terminal, so the SELECT returns my row.  Editing

Comment: Don't concatenate strings into the console. Try `console.log('results =', results)` or if that's not useful, stringify any objects, eg `console.log('results', JSON.stringify(results))`

Comment: Try passing the literal string '210871461580242946' just as a sanity check. Also, assuming that you're using [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com) it is recommended that you use [parameterized queries](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query) like `pool.query('SELECT * FROM xp WHERE id = $1', ['210871461580242946'], (err, results) => { ... })`